# How to do lower_bound on vector of objects

Tags: c++, stl, lower-bound

i was wondering if it is possible to do lower_bound on vector of objects, but without overloading operator< ? To be more precise i have vector of objects, which have one attribute (one of many). I'm pushing objects inside that vector as i order so i know it is sorted. Attribute which i mentioned is changing, to be more specific values are decresing by value of measured time. And measured time is time of the loop. So f.e. vector with starting values {1, 4, 5, 8, 10}, after first loop will have values { 0.5, 3.5, 4.5, 7.5, 9.5}, and so on. And i want to pop out elelemnts of that vector when they reach value of zero. And finali i want to do lower_bound to find how many of that objects have value of that attribute lower than 0.

Comment: how did you sort it when there is no `operator<` ?

Comment: [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) can take `binary_op` (instead of using `operator<`)

Comment: @idclev 463035818 Well, i not exactly do sort. I've just know that my data is sorted because i have pushed those data in exact order

Comment: @Jared42 i'm not sure if i know what to do with that information - sorry ;/

Comment: then you do not need `lower_bound`, you know how many elements are lower than zero at the time you push the elements in the vector, simply count them

Comment: "what to do with that information" follow the link, it has all you need to know, if you dont understand you could ask a more specific question. (not trying to be snarky btw, its just easier to help after you read some reference rather than before)

Comment: @idclev 463035818 i don't have those informations, because those data are changing. So i know at the beginning what value are there, but it is changing. And yeah, i understand you, thanks for helping me anyway. I think i know already how to solve my problem.

Comment: i dont understand, if it is changing then the vector is not sorted anymore and you also cannot use `lower_bound`

Comment: @idclev 463035818 it is changing, to be more specific values are decresing by value of measured time. And measured time is time of the loop. So f.e. vector with starting values {1, 4, 5, 8, 10}, after first loop will have values { 0.5, 3.5, 4.5, 7.5, 9.5}, and so on. And i want to pop out elelemnts of that vector when they reach value of zero. Is it more clear now?

Comment: yes that makes sense. Please consider to update your question with that information, because without that it is not clear why you need `lower_bound`

Comment: seems better then to have reverse vector and pop_back negative elements

Comment: @Jarod42 or `resize` after counting what to keep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (untested code)

```
std::vector<int> nums { 1,2,3,4,5 };
auto res = std::lower_bound(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 3, [](const int& a, const int& b){ return a<b;});
```

Comment: @Tojmak its so std::lower_bound can compare the element from the vector with the target value 3.

Comment: okay, but why i have to give "a" and "b"? I assume that "a" is element of my nums vector, and i want to find first value greater than 3 in your example

Comment: yeah, but i give to lower_bound 3 as argument. So is it like i redefine whole compare with that lambda? I mean for example "a" have a value from nums vector, and "b" take value of 3?

Comment: @Tojmak yes, if you exchange the int with some struct it might make more sense to do it this way.

Comment: but if i know that it is 3 for example, than i still have to give "b" as an argument? I mean, cannot i just do { return a < 3; }?